# What is the right way of making continuous ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, iis

I have some code like this to update a graph on my page in real-time every 30 seconds:

```
var counter = 30;

$(function() {
    prepare();
    update();
});

function update() {
    $("#timer").html("Refreshing in " + counter + " seconds...");
    counter--;

    if (counter == 0) {
        counter = 30;
        prepare();
    }

    setTimeout(update, 1000);
}

function prepare() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Service.asmx/GetPlotData",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: OnSuccess, // this function plots the new data
        error: OnError
    });
}
```

This seems to be working fine except after 16-20 hours of continuously making ajax calls, I get an error back from the server:

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a
>   connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled
>   connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

I fired up the debug console and this is what I observe:

### AJAX calls are getting fired correctly

[image]

### Before the 16-20 hour period, there are some instances where the latency increase (this is where the `Timeout` error is seen for the first time)

[image]

### Finally, the code manages to hit some bottleneck. Latency increases for every single call and the front-end breaks. No call after the blue arrow below returns any data. Instead, it throws the timeout error.

[image]

I am sure I am doing something fundamentally wrong. Any ideas on how to address this problem?

### EDIT: Server-side code

My connection string:

```
Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

The code to pull the records:

```
try
{
    string ConString = Constants.connString;
    con = new SqlConnection(ConString);

    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    con.Open();
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        // Add the records into an object
    }

}
catch (Exception x)
{
     // Send back some error text.
     // This is what is giving out the Timeout error
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

Unless I am missing something, I am closing the connection after getting the records using the `con.Close()` or is there anything else I need to do?

## EDIT 2: Changing the above code as follows. Is this correct?

```
try
{
    string ConString = Constants.connString;

    using (con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        con.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            // Add rows to object
        }
    }

}
catch (Exception x)
{
    // Handle error
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: keep track of how many calls have been made, you'll probably find it's some "familiar" power-of-2 or power-of-10 number. if that's the case, then you're hitting a browser limit. if it's some random number, then something else is in play

Comment: @MarcB: Thank you. I'll instrument the code. Why exactly is the browser limit coming into play here? At least the initial AJAX calls seem to be completed just fine or am I missing something else?

Comment: I haven't done any 16+hour runtime scripts in a long while, but I do remember that there was some quick in the settimeout stuff that each subsequent self-scheduled timeout added on layer to a call stack. could be something is keeping ghosts of the ajax calls alive in that stack, eventually exhausing the internal pool for such things.

Comment: I think your problem is in the server code, not the client code you posted, that seems fine.

Comment: @Nelson: Added the server-side code to my question too. From what I can understand, I am closing the connection after every query to the DB. Do you see anything suspicious?

Comment: I have an app that does nearly the exact same thing except uses a simple PHP backend; The JavaScript is almost certainly fine (our app doing this has run for 3+ weeks with no need to restart); it is server-side IMO.

Comment: Just wondering, are you using dojo for ploting the graph? I had similar problems because of it.

Comment: @Hoffmann: Nope. I am using `flot` http://code.google.com/p/flot/ But I am 100% certain that is not the graphing library's fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a server-side issue with too many connections to a database. How're you connecting to the DB? Are you closing the connection after using it? Try closing the connection after a number of connections.

Answer (score 1):

"I get an error back from the server" makes me think this is a server side resource leak.  What happens if you run two browser tabs in parallel, or two browsers in parallel, or two hosts with their own browsers hitting the server in parallel?

Does your browser memused rise over time?

If you have access to server side logs, that would also be a point to dive in.

**EDIT**

After seeing server code, you may want to close the reader as well for safety; I would be surprised if this caused a leak, but you never know.  I'm more familiar with Java, where this can cause a leak depending on the underlying driver being used.

```
dr.Close();
con.Close();
```

Comment: Actually, it looks like I am not closing the connection properly on the server side (at least that is what it seems like).